# Our fusion tables lost all their styling soon after a minor change

Tags: google-fusion-tables

I have series of fusion tables views of the same table, with each of the views using different columns for styling of polygon fill or gradient. The original table is itself a merge of several tables.

Soon after I made a change to only one of the view (changing the polygon fill color gradient), which was fine for bout the first half-hour or so, the styling started acting funny. It's now about 2 hours later, and the map is loading in gray with hand ("Data may still be loading"). Was wondering if this change of styling is related to every view having their styling acting weirdly. Here's the base table from which the views are made: https://www.google.com/fusiontables/embedviz?viz=MAP&q=select+col6%3E%3E1+from+1tGJyhsf9R2F9zFSmcsuleLYGLLcAXR0fTLzBX5g&h=false&lat=54.72855272934226&lng=-68.35017360696594&z=5&t=1&l=col6%3E%3E1

Or perhaps they're just some temporary rendering issues with Fusion Tables?

Thank you!

Comment: Well, it seems like it was a temporary problem, which, that said, did not only affect those tables mentioned, but all our other, simpler Fusion Tables...

Answer (score 0):

There was a temporary issue that we have have resolved.  Thanks for reporting the problem.